# Design issues supporting both orientations using apple guidelines

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AlternateViews/Introduction/Intro.html) one should have 2 controllers and 2 nibs in order to support landscape and portrait orientations.

The problem is this sample is very simple.  In my project I have a far more complex situation and its an iPad app so its far more work.

The problem that I have is:

A - duplication of code

> (both
>   controllers have the same code because
>   the UI is that similar) 
>   Blockquote

B - processing

> needs to be repeated e.g.  in portrait
>   the app loads, data is retrieved and
>   processed e.g. images are created etc
>   then the user switches to landscape,
>   this data needs to be retrieved again
>   or at least processed again.

How do I share the code and the data between the 2 controllers?

Comment: Where do you see that requirement, it sounds absurd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two controllers and nibs is not a requirement or even necessary. By properly setting the autoresizing mask for your views, you can frequently avoid any additional code.

If the autoresizing behavior isn't sufficient, the easiest way to create two view controllers is to create one parent `UIViewController` and two children view controllers.

Comment: and 2 nibs?  Can the outlets be in the parent UIViewController because I had a nightmare with that before.